# multiple select in select django orm

Tags: django, postgresql, orm

I need make this stament throw ORM in Django, but idk how to make it.

```
SELECT
    table_1.id,
    (SELECT COALESCE(SUM(qty_1), 0) FROM table_2 WHERE table_2.fk = table_1.id AND date BETWEEN start_date AND end_date),
    (SELECT COALESCE(SUM(qty_2), 0) FROM table_2 WHERE table_2.fk = table_1.id AND date BETWEEN start_date AND end_date),
    (SELECT COALESCE(SUM(qty_3), 0) FROM table_2 WHERE table_2.fk = table_1.id AND date BETWEEN start_date AND end_date)
FROM
    table_1
```

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Plz help me, I tried find this question here without any luck.

Answer (score 0):

Someone can show the direct way to do this many-to-many relationships.  I normally build that junction object separately.  So I'd do something like this:

```
class Options(...):
    name = models.CharField(...)
    ...

class Question(...):
    question = models.CharField(...)
    type = ...
    ...

 class QuestionResponseRegistry(...):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
    option = models.ForeignKey(Option)
    value = ...
```

So basically you build your own junction object.  I might as well point out the obvious before somebody else calls me and you out.  We are both to different extents using django incorrectly.  The whole power of django's ORM is to abstract higher than mapping to distinct SQL operations.  I laid out a way of linking a junction object by building the junction object directly, but in doing so am in some ways not just building a better defined data model with [many-to-many or one-to-many relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/examples/).